# nginx proxying to upstream apache server which has self-certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

As already mentioned in title, I have nginx server and apache server.Apache server has self-certificate because the settings are for development purpose.Also using nginx is for development purpose.Here is my config file for upstream server

```
server {
    server_name enhi.com
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    localtion / {
       proxy_pass https://172.17.0.3;
       proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.pem;
       proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;
    }
```

So here is the tricky thing on which I dont understand.
When I access

```
http://enhi.com
```

It will redirect me to my apache app with https protocol.And if I enter
    https://enhi.com
The browser gives me some "unexpected close ...." error.
So I don't understand what is going on in here.

Your help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The specific directive you want is [`proxy_ssl_verify`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_verify). However by default is disabled so out of the box, you should not be having issues. Most likely your issue is elsewhere.

Assuming it has been enabled, you should be see errors in the NGINX error log.

Comment: thanks @Joshua DeWald. It seems I missed some configs.I will let you know after I fixed the configs